# Dealing with Over-hyped AI questions

Tags: discussion, moderators

I came across this [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/10396/artificial-intelligence-and-its-unlawful-use). Clearly the question is badly formatted, but besides that its speculative and based on overhyped information about AI.

Are my conclusions on this question wrong? If not how can we make beginners in AI aware about the amount of false information floating around(Basically I am asking what is the remedial measures to such questions keeping in mind we don't want to scare away new visitors)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, badly formatted posts should be fixed; that is what the wiki-style editing is for.

But that specific question should be closed as `primarily opinion-based` because it is soliciting arguments and debate centered around a vague premise built on a hypothetical future which does not currently exist. Please don't let this site become [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It is not a good fit for this site.

But to answer your question more generally, if the premise of a question is wrong or misleading — whether by misunderstanding or pop culture hype — you should answer in a way that dispels the mistaken belief. Head off the incorrect information or assumption with a cohesive answer explaining the issue correctly.

Folks around the Internet are searching for this (mis)information wherever they can find it. It would nice if they landed ***here*** to straighten out the issue authoritatively.

Comment: What do you think about things which you cannot deny or approve...Like 'parallel government'..Can't deny nor can assure it's existence....Like God based topics (can't prove or disprove). What should be done then?

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a great deal of debate about this subject in general in the wider AI community (ethics re: implementation of AI).

That said, the question is poorly worded, and overly focuses on the proffered scenario, as opposed to the underlying general issue.

I've retagged (ethics, social, legal) and have provisionally closed the question, pending clarification.

Comment: The problem here is not the question itself but the solution...I can easily vote to close the question or downvote it, but it will give the new user a bad experience.

Comment: @DuttaA  In this case, although it partly a factor of bad, un-re-retranslated translation, I was unable to extract a line of thinking related to AI specifically.  I left it closed after OP edit b/c it's filled with ALL CAPS click-baity, polarizing keywords, which suggests ulterior motives.  (Distinct from noob OPs with earnest question who might not know how to ask them properly yet, being new to the field or self taught. It's these folks we want to encourage, not the really passionate ones who can't form a cogent, on-topic, answerable question.)